# How to access one midlet from another midlet in j2me

Tags: java-me, midlet

I have two different midlets. Is it possible to call one midlet from the other?

Answer (score 0):

See this useful links given below,

[Launching a Midlet from another Midlet](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/launching-a-midlet-from-another-midlet.html)

[Existing discussion same on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295647/can-a-midlet-invoke-another-midlet)